# Using blender model in A-Frame

Tags: vr

I created a model on Blender, and noticed the model seemed to be glitching. Changing the View clip start and end resolved the issue on Blender. Now, adding the same model to A-frame the same is happening but I can't seem to change the clipping. Is there a better solution, either for A-frame or the model itself in Blender?
The model was exported in glb.

The model in A-frame:
[image]

The model in Blender:
[image]

Comment: We have no idea what "A-frame" is and in any case this Q&A site can only help with problems in Blender and its built-in addons, not with external programs. Changing the camera (View) clipping in Blender isn't going to affect external programs anyway because that's purely a visual effect.

Comment: @JohnEason I understand, but when I tried Stack overflow, they told me the same thing about Blender and send me here :)